# SQL Dynamic Transpose of Category Term Table Without Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple problem here which I suspect has a simple solution that I am just overlooking.

I have a table of categories and terms (the category names are dynamic) which I would like "transposed". The result isn't really a strict table it's more like a result set that has single columns containing the terms associated with it with no relation to adjacent columns.

I have tried using a pivot but it is unsuitable due to having obvious null values across categories.

Here is a contrived example:

Example table setup:

```
create table #ExampleCats (termid int, Category nvarchar(100), Term nvarchar(100))
insert into #ExampleCats  VALUES 
 (34,'Location','North')
,(36,'Location','South')
,(38,'Location','East')
,(39,'Location','West')
,(42,'Location','Central')
,(155,'Color','Magenta')
,(156,'Color','Green')
,(157,'Color','Yellow')
,(161,'Color','Blue')
,(177,'Color','Red')
,(263,'Type','A')
,(274,'Type','B')
,(299,'Type','C')
,(512,'Material','Plastic')
,(513,'Material','Metal')
,(511,'Material','Wood')
--...other unknown names of category
```

Example query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM #ExampleCats c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')--select  @cols

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select term,term[t2],category
                from #ExampleCats
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(term)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
--print(@query)
execute(@query)
```

Result set:

[image]

Which gives me almost what I need, it's dynamic and returns all the terms under their associated categories. But obviously, since it is a table there are a lot of null gaps. Here is a screenshot of what I want the output too look like. Am I just asking poor old SQL to produce a "table" that it just can't?

[image]

I can't find any similar question regarding simple dynamic transposition. Also I think pivot might be overkill since there isn't technically any aggregation of the data values.

Comment: @lptr That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. If you add this as an answer then I'll tick it.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a sub query per category of one line.We then have a very simple query to show the lists side by side. NB The lists dont show properly in markdown.
If the number of categories is variable this query could be prepared dynamically.

> ```
> create table #ExampleCats (termid int, Category nvarchar(100), Term nvarchar(100))
> insert into #ExampleCats  VALUES
>  (34,'Location','North')
> ,(36,'Location','South')
> ,(38,'Location','East')                           ,(39,'Location','West')
> ,(42,'Location','Central')                        ,(155,'Color','Magenta')
> ,(156,'Color','Green')                            ,(157,'Color','Yellow')
> ,(161,'Color','Blue')                             ,(177,'Color','Red')
> ,(263,'Type','A')                                 ,(274,'Type','B')
> ,(299,'Type','C')                                 ,(512,'Material','Plastic')
> ,(513,'Material','Metal')                         ,(511,'Material','Wood');
>                                                   
> SELECT                                            l.A,
> Location,
>  Color,
>  Ttype 'Type',
>  Material             FROM
> (SELECT 1 A, STRING_AGG(Term, Char(10)) Location FROM #ExampleCats WHERE Category='Location') as l
> JOIN (SELECT 1 A,  STRING_AGG(Term, Char(10)) Color FROM #ExampleCats WHERE Category='Color') as c ON l.A=c.A
> JOIN (SELECT 1 A,  STRING_AGG(Term, Char(10)) Ttype FROM #ExampleCats WHERE Category='Type') as t ON l.A=t.A
> JOIN (SELECT 1 A,  STRING_AGG(Term, Char(10)) Material FROM #ExampleCats WHERE Category='Material') as m ON l.A=m.A
>
>  
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  A | Location                                  | Color                                     | Type        | Material                
> -: | :---------------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------- | :---------- | :-----------------------
>  1 | North<br>South<br>East<br>West<br>Central | Magenta<br>Green<br>Yellow<br>Blue<br>Red | A<br>B<br>C | Plastic<br>Metal<br>Wood
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87d504bff96ec14a28f4c3d58556ab80)*